# PHP building table and grouping results based on column

Tags: php

So, I'm already grouping and ordering within MySQL query and due to layouts, I'm not able to play with the query much more.

```
  $sql = "SELECT a.name AS agcname, m.npa, m.nxx, COUNT( m.npa ) AS ooscount,e.rcabbr,s.l_state
FROM MTAs m
INNER JOIN AGCs a ON a.id = m.agcid
LEFT JOIN endoffice.endoff e ON e.npa = m.npa
INNER JOIN endoffice.state s ON s.s_state = e.state
AND e.nxx = m.nxx
WHERE agcid =  '".$agcid."'
GROUP BY npa, nxx
ORDER BY rcabbr ASC";
```

This query gives me results like this:

```
agcname     npa nxx ooscount    rcabbr      l_state
agc02lttnco 818 575 1           AGOURA      CALIFORNIA
agc02lttnco 818 597 1           AGOURA      CALIFORNIA
agc02lttnco 562 598 1           ALAMITOS    CALIFORNIA
agc02lttnco 562 343 3           ALAMITOS    CALIFORNIA
agc02lttnco 562 386 7           ALAMITOS    CALIFORNIA
agc02lttnco 562 438 1           ALAMITOS    CALIFORNIA
agc02lttnco 562 433 1           ALAMITOS    CALIFORNIA
agc02lttnco 562 987 1           ALAMITOS    CALIFORNIA
agc02lttnco 719 589 2           ALAMOSA     COLORADO
agc02lttnco 719 937 2           ALAMOSA     COLORADO
agc02lttnco 719 992 1           ALAMOSA     COLORADO
```

I then use PHP to group the results based on the ratecenter (rcabbr) and combine the ooscount to build a row with rate center and all NPA NXX's tied to that rate center.

This is the code I'm using to do that.

```
  $result = $conn->query($sql);
  if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
      $agcrow = "";
      $agcname = $row['agcname'];
      $ooscount = $row['ooscount'];
      $npa = $row['npa'];
      $nxx = $row['nxx'];
      $rcabbr = $row['rcabbr'];
      $l_state = $row['l_state'];
      $npanxx = "".$npa."".$nxx."";

      if (isset($rc) && $rc != $rcabbr) {
          $agcrow .= "</td><td>".$rcoos."</td>\n                     </tr>\n";
          unset($rcoos);
          unset($rc);
          unset($st);

      }    

      if (!isset($rc)) {
          $rc = $rcabbr;
          $st = $l_state;
          $agcrow .= "\n<tr>     
                       <td>" . $agcname. "</td>   
                       <td>".$rc."</td>   
                       <td>".$l_state."</td>
                       <td><A href=\"".$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']."?agcid=".$agcid."&npa=".$npa."&nxx=".$nxx."\">".$npanxx."</a><BR>\n";
      } else {
          $agcrow .= "<A href=\"".$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']."?agcid=".$agcid."&npa=".$npa."&nxx=".$nxx."\">".$npanxx."</a><BR>\n";   
      }
      $rcoos = $rcoos + $ooscount;

      echo $agcrow;
    }
  }
```

The end result is rows that resemble the following:

```
 agc01   lawerence   kansas  909123   1231
                             909124
                             909125
                             909126
 agc01   hayes       kansas  909223   265
                             909224
 agc01   wallaby     kansas  909333   
                             909334
```

After I get the data I need/want, I use jquery datatables to make it sortable.

The problem I'm having is that the last row is missing the count due to how my logic is implemented. I struggled with figuring out how to even accomplish this but managed to make it work with this one little quirk.

How can I go about this the correct way so that I have that last column on that last row?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was way overthinking this apparently. The var rcoos would have stayed after the while loop continue finished, so it was just a matter of adding the var at the end.

```
    </td>
    <td><?=$rcoos?></td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do your summing already in sql:

```
$sql2 = "SELECT t.rcabbr, SUM(t.ooscount) FROM ($sql) t GROUP BY t.rcabbr"
```

Comment: Interesting, not sure how I would implement that though.

Comment: instead of  $result = $conn->query($sql); call  $result = $conn->query($sql2);

Comment: OK, thanks. That gives me Rate Center and total oos counts only unfortunately. This method seems more logical, but I'm a bit of a newb still. AGOURA     2
ALAMITOS   13
ALAMOSA   6
ALHAMBRA   19
ALLIANCE   3

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f204d9/13   this may help to show the database side of the project.

Comment: sorry, from your post it is quite hard to decipher what you actually display in the resulting table, but I think you have the domain knowledge so you would do, take care